# data parallelism in spark : reading avro data from hdfs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read avro data using scala within spark environment. My data is not getting distributed and while running it is going to 2 nodes only. we have 20+nodes. Here is my code snippet

```scala
@serializable case class My_Class (val My_ID : String )

val filePath = "hdfs://path";

val avroRDD = sc.hadoopFile[AvroWrapper[GenericRecord], NullWritable, AvroInputFormat[GenericRecord]](filePath)

val rddprsid = avroRDD.map(A =>
    new My_Class(new String(A._1.datum.get("My_ID").toString()))
);

val uploadFilter = rddprsid.filter(E => E.My_ID ne null);
val as = uploadFilter.distinct(100).count;
```

I am not able to use parallelize operation on the rdd as it complaints about the following error.

```
<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper[org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord], org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable)]
 required: Seq[?]
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: This is 2 different questions, of which the first does not have enough information. What is your spark-submit?

Comment: I am submitting job using scala console and it is on yarn client.

Comment: By scala console, do you mean spark-shell?

Comment: yes, spark-shell -- master yarn-client.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing only 2 nodes because yarn submission defaults to 2. You need to submit with `--num-executors [NUMBER]` and optionally `--executor-cores [NUMBER]`

As to the parallelize....you're data is already parallelized...thus the wrapper around `RDD`. `parallelize` is only for use to take in-memory data across the cluster.

Comment: Hi @Justin Pihony, I am trying to get app wise unique user count, my program is giving me correct result if it is single part file. when I run it for 10 files, I believe it calculating UU per part file and summming them. Can you please help?                                                                            val appMap = avroRDD.map(A => (new App_userid(A._1.datum.get("App").toString, A._1.datum.get("user").asInstanceOf[Long]),1));
 val dist = appMap.reduceByKey(_+_,500)
 val newmap = dist.map(a => (a._1.App,1));
 val newval = newmap.reduceByKey(_+_);
 val finalResult =  newval.collect;

Comment: This should be a separate question. My original answer dealt with your original question. Removing the accepted check because you have a new problem is not how SO works.

Comment: Thanks Justin. I have created a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33512015/distinct-is-not-working-in-spark-using-custom-key